# Name of most general operator on probabilities whose output are also probabilities?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Not sure if the title is correct phrasing, I'll try to explain.

Consider finite domain discrete probabilities for simplicity and illustration. The n-probabilities are contained on a (n-1)-simplex such that $p_1+\dots+p_n=1$. What is the terminology of the most general operator that maps a simplex to a simplex? (That is, from n probabilities to a m probabilities)

**Example:**
Linear transformation, in general, are not allowed,

$f([p_1, p_2, p_3]) = [-p_1, -p_2, -p_3]$ (not a valid distribution)

but special linear transformation are: one such being

$f([p_1, p_2, p_3]) = [p_1+p_2, p_3]$,

another could be

$f([p_1, p_2, p_3]) = [.5 p_1, .7 p_3, p_2, .5 p_1, .3 p_3]$.

These are linear, but non-linear can also be function, consider binomial distribution after two flips $f([1-p, p]) = [(1-p)^2, 2p(1-p), p^2]$

Two probability distribution can also be inputs, such as estimating the joint distribution of a 2x2 by the two margins assuming independence, $g([1-a, a],[1-b,b])=[(1-a)(1-b), (1-a)b ,a(1-b) ,ab]$

What is the most general property that $f()$ must have? That is if it doesn't have that property there exists a valid input which would produce an invalid output which is not a probability distribution?

Edit:
I know that all output $p_i>0$ an sum($p_i$)=1 is a property but is there a way to verify that is true without having to verify each output  $p_i>0$ ,for example. The $i$th output $p_i$ could be a complicated non-linear function of inputs probabilities which may be hard or even impossible to test for each $i$ but if we can state that

$\left( f(\text{n-simplex}) \mapsto  \text{m-simplex} \right) \iff \text{f is ???}$

Comment: I don't see any reason there should be a term for such a broad concept: you could invent one if you like.  The most general property $f$ can have is already exhibited in your question: it need merely map a simplex into a simplex.  This is a consequence of the axioms of probability: all probabilities must be non-negative and sum to unity.  That *defines* the simplices.  Your edit seems to refer to a context that so far has not been revealed: namely, you appear to conceive of a function more narrowly in terms of *an algorithm* rather than in the usual mathematical sense.